# C# - format specific number using format.string in runtime (live) on texbox

Tags: c#, runtime, live, string.format

i made code to format number when total lengh is == 11, it run on texbox change, but only format when it have 11 characters, i would like to make it on runtime (live), understood ? Its possible ? See my code:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Int64 cpf = Convert.ToInt64(textBox3.Text);
            if (textBox3.TextLength == 11)
            {
                textBox3.Text = string.Format(@"{0:000\.000\.000-00}", Convert.ToInt64(cpf));
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Nope, I didn't understand what means *make it on runtime*

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I was literally thinking the same thing! It's in `runtime` already. :D

Comment: i am braziliam, not speak english very well.. What i mean is, for example, if user type 1, it will convert to 000.000.000-01, if type 12, it will convert to 000.000.000-12, if type 123, it will convert to 000.000.001-23, undertood ? intead wait user type all numbers (ex: 11804852598 to convert to 118.048.525-98) it will make live (problem that i found that when make live it change textbox value), understood now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lazyberezovsky stated, use a masked textbox, but set the [PromptChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.promptchar.aspx) to whatever you want. Something along the lines of:

```
//In your form_load
//Based on your code above, assuming textBox3 is a MaskedTextbox    
textBox3.KeyUp += CheckEvent()
textBox3.Mask = "000000000000";
textBox3.PromptChar = 'x'; //set this to a space or whatever you want ' ' for blank!

//check AFTER every key press
private void CheckEvent(object Sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox3.Text.Count() < 12)
    {
        return;
    }

    //change the textboxMask when all chars present
    maskedTextBox1.Mask = "0:000.000.000-00";
}
```

Comment: its near perfect, but for example, when i add this: on mask 000.000.000-00 and promptchar as " ", my field before user type show: "   .   .   -  ", i would like to hide these characters, only show them after user type values in field, like: if type 118, show 118., if type 118048, show 118.048, understood ? Hide . and - until user type qty to arrive that character.. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the edited code, this isn't perfect, but have a play around with it, the concept is to check when a key has been pressed using the KeyUp event and if all the numbers are present (12), change the mask.

Comment: I edited it, its returning error: Error 1 No overload for method 'CheckEvent' takes 0 arguments

Comment: worked, code is good, thanks for that. It hide all characters like . and - until i select field and start type, on first letter start formating, but not make it dinamical, like pure maskedtextbox does, had to have option to hide . and - in runtime..

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [MaskedTextbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) with `Mask` equal to `000.000.000-00`. It will fill mask in usual way from left to right. Input will look like:

```
___.___.___-__
```

When use types `1` it will show `1__.___.___-__`.
When use types `12` it will show `12_.___.___-__`. And so on.

Comment: I know this command, problem are these ___ that i dont want.. know how change it for " " instead "_" ?

Comment: @felipeSalomao underscores show user positions that should be filled. As I understand you need all numbers to be typed. So, that will show to user that input is not finished yet.